# Encapsulation VS Inheritance - How to use a protected function?

Tags: c#, vb.net, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

In OOP languages like C# or VB.NET, if I make the properties or methods in a super class `protected` I can't access them in my Form - they can only be accessed in my class that inherits from that super class.

To access those properties or methods I need to make them `public`, which defeats encapsulation, or re-write them into my class, which defeats inheritance.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"need to make them public which defeats encapsulation"

Don't conflate good design with the icky visibility rules.  The visibility rules are confusing.  There are really two orthogonal kinds of visibility -- subclass and client.  It's not perfectly clear why we'd ever conceal anything from our subclasses.  But we can, with `private`.

Here's what's important.  Encapsulation does not mean hiding.  Protected and private are not an essential part of good encapsulation.  You can do good design with everything being public (that's the way Python works, for example).

The protected/private stuff is -- mostly -- about intellectual property management: are you willing to commit (in a legally binding, "see-you-in-court-if-it-doesn't-work" way) to an interface?  If your software development involves lawyers, then you care about adding protect and private to the things you're not committed to.

If you don't have to cope with lawyers, consider doing encapsulation right but leave everything public.

Answer (score 2):

If you have code which needs to ask an Class to perform a specific operation but the class does not present your code with a means to do that then the Class doesn't fulfill you codes requirements.

Its bit like saying I've got a Car (Automobile) that has a protected steering wheel so I can't access it.  The car is no use to me.

Either make those members Public (or at least internal) and use them or ditch the class and use one that gives your consuming code the features it needs.

Perhaps what you are really looking for is an interface.  The interface contains the members your code needs and you implement that interface on your class.  The advantage here is that your class can determine that the members are being accessed via this Interface rather than an inheriting subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not clear what you mean by "in my Form" - what is the relationship between your Form and your two classes? If your classes are controls in the same project, and you want to access properties from the form, you should use the 'internal' keyword.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three ways you can limit who can use some particular instance method of particular class instances:

1. Define the method as `protected`, `internal`, or `private`.  In the first case, an instance method will only be usable from within derived-class methods of the same instance; in the second case, all classes within the assembly will have access to those methods, but classes outside won't; in the third case, no outside classes, even derived ones in the same assembly, will have access, unless their code is nested within the declaring class.

   Define the method as `public`, but have the classes that create instances keep them private and never expose them to the outside world.  Anyone wanting to invoke an instance method on an object has to have an instance to invoke it on.  If a class holds instances but never exposes direct references to them, the only instance methods that can ever be used on those instances will be those which the holding classes uses itself.

   Define the method as `public`, but have a constructor which accepts a location into which one or more delegates to private methods may be stored.  Code with access to those delegates will be able to call the methods referred to thereby, but other code will not (except by using Reflection in ways which I think are only usable in full-trust scenarios).

If Reflection in non-full-trust scenarios would allow unbound delegates to be bound to arbitrary object instances, one could use nested classes to reinforce #3 so that one would have to access `private` fields to gain illegitimate access to the `private` functions; that would definitely be forbidden outside full-trust scenarios.